# How to map table from databricks to Azure Data Warehouse using external table?

Tags: azure, type-conversion, databricks

I try to create external table in Azure DataWarehouse from table in Azure Databricks. I fail to convert a few column types such as date and dcimal.

Example of my table structure in the databricks:

[image]

Table schema in azure data warehouse:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table.NAME (
    aBooleanFlag BIT NULL
    ,bIntID int NULL
    ,cStringColumn VARCHAR(50)
    ,dDateColumns   DATETIME    null
    ,eMoneyAmount   DECIMAL(13,3)   null
)
WITH(DATA_SOURCE=[DS_DTS_LAKE], LOCATION=N'//Folder/Table/', FILE_FORMAT=[ParquetFileFormat], REJECT_TYPE=VALUE, REJECT_VALUE=0) ;
GO
```

What have i tried so for:

1. I've arranged column in alpabetic order as I have noticed sometimes external table does not map columns correctly
2. I converted all columns to string and table **was** created successfuly
3. I tried casting to different column data types such as DoubleType() or float without any luck. Instead, I get error message below:

**Error message:**
Msg 106000, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: ClassCastException:

4. I'm considering creating an external table again with all columns being string and then creating a view on top of it with proper conversion.

Please advise how to proper map data types or wheter view option is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution just by accident. I've changed conversion to the following:

```
from DecimalType(13,3) to DecimalType(24,10)
from DateType to TimestampType
```